# Hiding Parent Theme

Tags: child-theme

I am using the child theme and have renamed it to the new theme name. However, the parent theme is still viewable in the admin area with the original theme name. How do I hide the parent theme? Thanks.

Comment: Just a simple plugin that add a little bid javascript source to hide the markup for this parent. Simple, but useful. Alternative use Adminimize plugin to do this, allow to create custom rule to hide areas.

Answer (score 9):

There is a filter called `wp_prepare_themes_for_js` in `wp-admin/includes/theme.php` in the `wp_prepare_themes_for_js()` function, which is called by `wp-admin/themes.php` to populate the theme set. That filter will allow you to remove themes from the list. Of course, you have to know the theme name.

```
function kill_theme_wpse_188906($themes) {
  unset($themes['twentyten']);
  return $themes;
}
add_filter('wp_prepare_themes_for_js','kill_theme_wpse_188906');
```

Comment: May be a newbie question.Although you refer to `wp_prepare_themes_for_js` you unset `themes`. I also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30780852/1527780) where they unset  and return the `prepared_themes`. Is there any difference? Do you have a preference and why?

Comment: No there is no difference. See, here in the function we passed the parameter as `$themes` and in there they did the same thing, but named the parameter `$prepared_themes`. So basically they are both identical. Just name of the parameter or passed variable is different which actually does not matter. @marikamitsos

Comment: @the_dramatist Sorry for the late reply. I somehow thought that `$themes` and `$prepared_themes` are two distinct, "standard", WordPress core parameters that are initiated in succession one after the other. Not arbitrary. From your comment it seems that is not the case. Thank you for clarifying that.